# Moving elements with html5/js ( Like the Apple Iphone website )

Tags: html

I'm looking for information on how to move elements like this : http://www.apple.com/iphone/
Switch between the slides to see what i mean.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything, e.g. have a look at jquery?

Comment: Yes i did. I think Clafou is right, they are using css transforms.        If it was jQuery it would work on other browsers as well and it's not the case. In other browsers, there's a 'simple' fade or slide effect between the slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using CSS transforms such as webkit-transform. There is an article at 
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/